# How do I replace AsyncTask with RxJava in Room methods?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, rx-java, rx-java2, android-room

I have an insert method that uses `Asynctask` to set a new item in the `Room` database. Can I get rid of the `InsertContactAsyncTask` class and switch to using `RxJava`? I can't find such examples on the Internet

method `insert`:

```
override fun insert(contact: Contact) {
        InsertContactAsyncTask().execute(contact)
}
```

`AsyncTask class`:

```
class InsertContactAsyncTask: AsyncTask<Contact, Unit, Unit>() {

        private val contactDao: ContactDao? = null

        override fun doInBackground(vararg param: Contact) {
            contactDao?.insert(param[0])
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fun insert(contact:Contact) : Completable
```

Then somewhere you call this method

```
contactDao.insert()
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.IO)
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.Main)
.subscribe{Log.d("test","insertcompleted")
//do something when insert completed
}
```

or just place insert into completable like this

```
fun insertCompletable(contact:Contact){
Completable.fromAction{contactDao.insert}
}
```

and subscribe to it the same way as previous

Answer (score 3):

```
override fun insert(contact: Contact) {
    Single.fromCallable { contactDao.insert(contact) }
          .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
          .subscribe()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Override insert method and receive the callback by subscribing it like :-

```
override fun insert(contact: Contact) {
Single.fromCallable { //Insert Query here }
      .subscribeOn(// thread )
      .subscribe()
```

}